# how to make the position of this div relative to the main container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, sorry for this dumb question. I am very bad at html.

i have this page. http://www.places4two.de/  If you resize the window, the ads div which is on the right side is overlapping the main container, what i want is to make this ads div relative to main container and if you resize, it should stop when it hits the main container. how can i do this.

this is what i tried:

```
 position: relative
```

and

```
 position: fixed
```

but they are not helping.

Comment: totally agreed with @galleryguy.

Comment: Have you tried adding overflow:hidden property to your main div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of your adsense is 160px, and you can set for the main container width as,

```
width: calc(100% - 160px);
```

here is the fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/jzwjP/2/**

would be its prototype, the adsense width remains constant 160px, while the big container width will be resizable depending on your browser, will be calculated by browser width minus adsense width.

Comment: i dont see anything on the right side of container

Comment: i see, but in the output i dont see it. i see only red area in the output

Comment: but anyway, i want my container not to be resizable, otherwise i will have to make things responsive. i just want that adsense div stops when he hits the container div, is it possible?

Comment: nope, i dont see that yellow part.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put the main content container and the advertisement in the same container. We'll call this container "wrapper". The width of `#wrapper` should equal to the width of the main content container plus the width of the ad, plus the margin between the two, plus the borders. It can be centered within the body using left and right margins of "auto".

Now inside the "wrapper" you can either float the main content container left and the ad container right, or you can use absolute positioning relative to `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1310px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#main-content {
    width: 1100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#ad {
    width: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```